# Getting ref null inside useCallback hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to set the value of input using ref but I'm getting ref null inside useCallback Hook.

```
let inputRef = useRef();
const search = useCallback(
        (data) => {
            console.log(inputRef);
        },
        [inputRef],
    );

return <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />
```

and It's showing `null` in the browser console when I call this function.

this is just an example showing, what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't that he's not passing in a null value, a ref is initialized to `null` by default.

The problem is that `useCallback()` memoizes and caches the result of this callback function before the first render, before the component to which this ref is assigned has been mounted. It then waits for `inputRef` to change but `inputRef` is just a reference to an object; even if the component that `inputRef.current` points to changes, the value of `inputRef` does not as it is only being compared by reference equality.

So, since the function has no reason to update as the value of `inputRef` is not going to change -- it evaluates to the cached result of the `search` callback which was computed and cached before the DOM mounted and it outputs `null` to console.

What you're looking for is a [Callback Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs)

[image]

The other thing that I'd like to point out is that the useCallback hook is not necessary for this use-case and will provide no benefit. The only correct usage of `useCallback()` is to cache the result of expensive function calls so that they don't recompute every time render is called (this is known as memoization).

The arbitrary usage of the useCallback() hook is an anti-pattern-- it is not required for the overwhelming majority of callbacks in React, and can reduce performance when used incorrectly by creating additional overhead.